# Limiting probability of a successful bid

Tags: probability, markov-chains

[image]

I'm having trouble completing the above question, as my working knowledge of "limiting probabilities" is not very good. For the 1-step transition matrix, I have $$P=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.6 & 0.4\\
0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.4 & 0.6 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.7 & 0.3\end{pmatrix}$$

To me, a "successful bid" is represented by going from $sf$ to $fs$, $ss$ to $ss$, $fs$ to $ss$ or $ff$ to $fs$. Is that a correct interpretation?

I've been looking through my professor's slides and trying very hard to understand how to apply $$\mathbf{\pi}^{(n)}=\mathbf{\pi}^{(0)}P^{n}$$
to my current problem. I think I understand that if I know the initial distribution, I know the distribution at time $n$, but I'm not sure what the initial distribution is for this problem...

Any help with how I can continue with this problem would be a great help.

Thanks in advance for your patience, all.

Comment: "trying very hard to understand how to apply $\mathbf{\pi}^{(n)} = \mathbf{\pi}^{(0)}P^{n}$ to my current problem." Maybe it is not necessary at all to apply this to your problem, for reasons explained in your notes.

Comment: @Did I'm really not understanding the idea, and was hoping a different perspective from somebody who has a better knowledge of Markov chains would be beneficial. Clearly, the notes aren't helping in this particular instance. But thank you for your response all the same.

Comment: ?? No theorem in your notes linking the matrix limit of $P^n$ to the distribution after a large number of steps?

Comment: @Did The notes go into detail with a two-state chain, and $\pi=\pi P$ comes up a lot. No theorems though, stated explicitly at least. I'm in an uphill battle at the moment. I enrolled in this probability course as I had completed the prerequisite courses, but have since realised that it assumes knowledge from two other later level math courses be trivial to us. I would not be posting on this site if I was confident I could infer a solution from the understanding I have of the notes.

Comment: Please note that I asked a quite specific question in my last comment, to which the answer is "yes there is" or "no there is not", and which involves no notion of understanding or confidence or whatever.

Comment: Far out man. "No theorems though, stated explicitly at least." I will waste no more of your time. I'm only interested in some guidance, preferably friendly. Apologies for my inefficient answer and ostensibly offensive level of knowledge of Markov chains.

Comment: Do they get interested in $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P^n$ in your notes? Do they say why? (Passive-aggressive comment duly noted.)

Comment: Sorry. Yes, they do. I understand that the question itself has that result included. My issue is most likely with my interpretation of the problem. Plus I'm not too sure how to read off the limiting matrix when I believe my answer involves multiple elements in the matrix.

Comment: Do they say why? (Bis repetita.)

Comment: Each element ($p_{ij}$) is the probability of moving from state $i$ to state $j$. $n$ is the number of bids in this case. As $n$ gets large, the matrix represents the limiting probabilities. But I can't just add up the elements which I think are relevant. If I do, my answer is above 1.

Comment: "As n gets large, the matrix represents the limiting probabilities." And do they say the limit of $(P^n)_{ij}$ when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: They do not say.

Comment: Well then they should (and they might, actually) mention that $(P^n)_{ij}\to\pi_j$ -- from which the answer to your question is direct.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that $(P^{n})_{1,3}$, $(P^{n})_{2,2}$, $(P^{n})_{3,2}$ and $(P^{n})_{4,3}$ need to be considered? In my mind they are all indicators of a successful bid.

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Well, again (and sincerely) I am sorry if I have wasted your time. I certainly do appreciate it. Thank you.